# Rspec validation failed - attribute can't be blank but it isn't blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just wrote a test for testing if a new user creation also consists of an admin setting. Here is the test:

```
describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      :name => "Example User", 
      :email => "user@example.com",
      :admin => "f"
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end

  it "should require a name" do
    no_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
    no_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require an email" do
    no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
    no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require an admin setting" do
    no_admin_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:admin => ""))
    no_admin_user.should_not be_valid
  end

end
```

Then, in my User model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :admin

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :projects, :through => :ownerships

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :admin, :presence => true

end
```

I clearly created a new user with an admin setting, so why is it saying it's false? I created the migration for the admin setting as admin:boolean. Did I do something wrong?

Here's the error:

```
Failures:

  1) User should create a new instance given valid attributes
     Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Admin can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Oddly enough, when I comment out validates :admin, :presence => true, the test creates the user correctly but fails on "User should require an admin setting"

EDIT: When I change the @attr :admin value to "t" it works! Why doesn't it work when the value is false?

Comment: Failures:

  1) User should create a new instance given valid attributes
     Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Admin can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence):

> Since false.blank? is true, if you want to validate the presence of a
>   boolean field you should use validates :field_name, :inclusion => {
>   :in => [true, false] }.

Basically, it looks like ActiveRecord is converting your "f" to `false` before the validation, and then it runs `false.blank?` and returns `true` (meaning that the field is NOT present), causing the validation to fail. So, to fix it in your case, change your validation:

```
validates :admin, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }
```

Seems a little hacky to me... hopefully the Rails developers will reconsider this in a future release.